# Template tags for Buddypress

Tags: templates, buddypress, php

Is there a place that shows all available template tags and how to use them similar to how wordpress does?

I'm trying to link to a profile within a loop.

Ex of output

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/members/Tom/">Tom's Profile</a>
```

Tried this

```
<?php echo( bp_core_get_userlink() ) ?>
```

but it errors out

This gives me the author name and url but i just need the url to the profile

```
<?php echo( bp_core_get_userlink( $post->post_author ) ) ?>
```

But I am not all that great with PHP so I can't figure out how to just output the url

Thoughts?

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=buddypress+template+tags&l=1

Comment: and to your 2nd question:  `echo bp_core_get_userurl($post->post_author);`

Comment: <?php echo bp_core_get_userurl($post->post_author); ?> fires an error , found this http://codex.buddypress.org/developer-docs/the-bp-global/ but not really sure how to use it.

Comment: ..and the error is?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function bp_core_get_userurl() in

Comment: <p><?php echo bp_core_get_userurl($post->post_author); ?></p> is what im using within a loop

Comment: maybe you need to call a bp header tag before that

Comment: <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

     <?php do_action( 'bp_before_blog_post' ) ?>

     <div class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
      <div class="author-box"><a href="#"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), '25' ); ?></a></div>
       <p><?php echo bp_core_get_userurl($post->post_author); ?></p>
 
     </div>

     <?php do_action( 'bp_after_blog_post' ) ?>
                    

    <?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: This is the entire loop, what is the code to bp header tag?

Comment: well this is the function: http://bp-dev.org/phpxref/bp-core.php.source.html#l784 Try inserting it somewhere above the loop and see if that works

Comment: same error. I need it in a loop though. I basically want to show the users avatar then when they click the avatar it takes them to their public profile page...

Comment: no, I mean copy the entire function from there, put it somewhere before the loop, then call it in the loop.

Comment: Sorry, how do you call something in the loop?

I put this above the loop, outside of it, <?php echo bp_core_get_userurl($post->post_author); ?> and got the same error

Comment: is there a way to display the user name within the loop? I could hard code it that way website.com/members/<?php echo username; ?>/

Comment: `get_the_author();`

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want to use bp_core_get_user_domain(); I think bp_core_get_userurl() was taken out after the first release of BuddyPress.